# Tomcat in combination with Intellij IDEA: no compiler available

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm just testing Intellij IDEA in combination with an Tomcat 7 serveron Arch Linux.

I got the standard Tomcat Page when starting Tomcat by

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/tomcat start
```

I just used tutorial at http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat to configure Intellij.

Just a blank project but running Tomcat and opening localhost:8080 in Webbrowser causes following exception:

```
Feb 22, 2012 11:38:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:228)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:638)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketWithOptionsProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1763)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm have no idea why the java compiler is missing. Java Home is set in Tomcat conf correct to

```
 /opt/java
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is `javac` present on your system?

Comment: Yes, javac is installed. Can be found in PATH

Answer (score 0):

The error is misleading, it can't find Jasper JSP compiler, not Java compiler.

It is `org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler`, and it can't be loaded from the classpath, meaning that most probably JAR file with it (`jasper.jar`) did not get there for some reason.

Did you download/unpacked Tomcat from apache, or did you install it from your Linux distribution repo? Distribution packages mangle package structure sometimes...

Comment: I installed tomcat from repo.

Comment: Could you please try to download it from apache, unpack, and configure it in Idea? I bet it will produce better results